# Best practice in if statements with multiple checks

Tags: php

I am creating a system that builds a page from a layout type of system.
Each of my layouts have a ton of variables like header, description, link, link-text, image, etc.

To get the styling to fit perfectly (styled with marging and padding in the bottom of each layout type) i need to check if any of the variables are filled, which puts me in a situation with an if statement with a ton of OR checks.

```
<?php if (!empty(get_sub_field('header')) || !empty(get_sub_field('text')) || !empty(get_sub_field('page_link')) || get_sub_field('image_or_video') != 'none' || !empty(get_sub_field('image')) || !empty(get_sub_field('video'))): ?>
    ## HTML GOES HERE
<?php endif ?>
```

So my question is, if there is an easier and more readable way to go around it?

Comment: Unify that somehow into one condition you need to check…?! E.g., set a variable `$needToDisplayFoo` somewhere else in your code, and you can use however much code you need to calculate its value correctly.

Comment: Thats actually genius.
Not that the way i did it is wrong in any way, but its a pain to write and look at.

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?
    if (get_sub_field('header')    or
        get_sub_field('text')      or
        get_sub_field('page_link') or
        get_sub_field('image')     or
        get_sub_field('video')     or
        get_sub_field('image_or_video') != 'none')
    {
    ?>
        ## HTML GOES HERE
    <?
    }
```

Also you can add extra method for multiple validation.

Comment: Imagine having 21 different layout types, which 3-9 checks each.
I agree that this is easy to read, indeed, but it would take up alot of space.